# How to parse bot framework message in node.js with user reference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, botframework

JavaScript is not my first language, but I still think this is difficult to parse:

```
<at id="28:aaaaaaa-5842-41ab-8511-4b3cc175aa2f">user</at> silver
```

I can't find a way to get the word "silver" after I run the line through an XML parser. Am I approaching this incorrectly?

PS - I added the quotes around the greater than and less than signs so the tag would appear - otherwise the entire tag disappears.

Comment: Need some more context.  Why / where are you using XML in the BotFramework?

Comment: This is the message in session.message.text (verbatim).  I want to get to the word "silver", and optimally know what the user is.